# Unable to add downloaded video from my computer to webpage with html

Tags: html

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="8Mile.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
```

This is how I've done it and I also tried

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="Videos/8Mile.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source> 
</video>
```

I saw in some example that they added another source tag for some associated .ogg file but I don't think my file has that.

Comment: Have you uploaded the video next to the HTML page, onto the server?

Comment: first you have to upload the video file in Videos folder

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto what server? I don't have one I've simply been working on a page for learning purposes and haven't uploaded it yet.

Comment: @LavanyaE how do I do that? Upload it onto where?

Comment: You use relative path in your `src` attribute, that means the video must be placed next to the HTML page, in your 2nd case the folder of the page must have a `Videos` folder, and the video file must be in that.

Comment: if you don't have upload function then place you video in (videos) folder